# AngularJS - Select default value with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/42SwC/)

I have an select tag which i am using `ng-model` to get the selected value. The Select tag shows Empty first value, it should be showing `Choose`. What i am doing wrong?

```
<select ng-model="todo.opts">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option><25%</option>
    <option>25-50%</option>
    <option>>50%</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your model will be empty to begin with, you can easily select the `Choose` option by giving it an empty value:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="opts">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option><25%</option>
        <option>25-50%</option>
        <option>>50%</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ayDC/).

Comment: Yep, but you should rather give a value for all those options, and set the default value in your controller

Comment: @edi9999 or use `ng-init` to set the default

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the todo.opts variable in the scope as the value you want to select as a default.
By the way check documentation for the **ng-option**